# Difference between JTA, JPA and plain JDBC in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, jta

What is the difference between JTA, JPA and plain JDBC in terms of Hibernate?

Answer (score 88):

In order for a difference to exist, there should be something in common, and apart from being database-related (although JTA is not only that), they have nothing more in common:

- JPA is a standard for Java object-relational mapping - it specifies a set of annotations and an interface -`EntityManager` to perform persistence operations with the mapped objects. Hibernate implements the JPA standard
- plain JDBC is a technology for accessing databases. It is what Hibernate actually uses to perform the database operations, "under the hood". It uses JDBC to send queries to the database.
- [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) is a transaction API, and it is optional in Hibernate. It handles (logically) the transaction behaviour.

Comment: So JTA is what is responsible for the roll back and commits when using an entity manager ? So JPA is using JTA ? Or is JTA used when you have say 2 database replicas ? Please answer I'm confused

Comment: `In order for a difference to exist, there should be something in common` - What is this an idea or a fact?

Comment: @Ced look at the answer bellow. [link o the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304566/7729614 ]

Answer (score 38):

- JDBC is a Java standard for database connection.
- JPA isolates the Java developer from the inner workings of JDBC and database operations.
  Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA and Data Nucleus are famous JPA implementations.
- JTA is a standard for transactions, allowing for management of multiple transactions among multiple databases.

JPA utilizes JDBC for database connections and SQL-related operations, and  -optionally- utilizes JTA for delegating distributed transaction management details to it.

Answer (score 10):

JPA (Java Persistence API) is the Java ORM standard/specification for storing, accessing, and managing Java objects in a relational database. Hibernate is an implementation of the Java Persistence API (JPA) specification.

JTA (Java Transaction API) is the Java standard/specification for distributed transactions. It comes into picture when you have transactions that spans across multiple connections/DBs/resources. Atomikos is an implementation of JTA. (Appservers like IBM Websphere has their own JTA implementations.)